# Blank screen when I build my app on XCode 7.1 for iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have the app presser package for app building but their files are very outdated. I have fixed most of the issues in the app but there is one issue I don't understand. The issue is with the following code:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.  
    // Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view     
    // controller decide what's allowed 
    //(the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = 
        (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | 
        (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | 
        (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | 
        (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

and the error I'm getting when I build it is:

> /Users/username/Desktop/Appfolder/platforms/ios/Appname/Classes/AppDelegate.m:138:1: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line to:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
```

and see if that fixes the warning. Basically the only change is to change the type of the returned value from `NSUInteger` to `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`.

In fact this method would probably look neater if written as follows:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.
    // Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view
    // controller decide what's allowed
    //(the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations =
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight |
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the kind help, the error is removed but there is still white blank screen, i think there is some others issue as well on the app.

Comment: The warning you were getting in your original question would not be responsible for a blank white screen.

Comment: The main issue is the plugins seems to be outdated. I am updating the cordova plugins now. Thanks again .